# How to implement virtual mouse c#

Tags: c#, blob, mouse, aforge

I'm building application to detect laser movement and convert this movement to mouse event.I use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]` to work with mouse
 When it detects one laser point it work correctly and control mouse movement.
I need it to work when it detects multiple lasers point which mean i need to have multiple mice working simultaneous.
 
How to make that and develop virtual mouse to work with multiple lasers points in same time. 
 It work with one mouse, one laser point correctly.

Comment: If you plug two, or three mice into a computer I don't think you'll find that works very well. Is that what you are saying you are trying to re-create?

Comment: @Belogix  yes i want to create virtual mouse !

Comment: My point was I don't think you can have multiple mice plugged into Windows and they all control the same pointer. What are you really trying to achieve? Are you trying to achieve more multiple "touch" type input rather than mouse?

Comment: @Belogix yes , i want we work with it to make same input event such as  movement and clicking in `winform` such as multiple mouse can draw in paint at same time with different input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `Microsoft MultiPoint Mouse SDK` that help me to do that [for more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff877472.aspx)
this help me to have any number of mouses in the same time by plug this mouse in my device